# Uwsgi logger : unable to find logger file

Tags: logging, uwsgi

I am using nginx with uwsgi.
in the uwsgi configuration file, whenever I use logger tag I get "unable to find logger file" error.

Here is the entry from my configuration file:
     nonok file:/tmp/uwsgi-us.log
     nonok (?!HTTP/1.\d 200)

Any pointer here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to enable the "logfile" plugin with a line like `plugins = logfile` or `plugins = python,logfile`.

Comment: It is not obvious to beginners like me that the plugins have to be enabled like this. Also, in this python3 world, the plugin is named "python3" because the error message helped: `UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python_plugin.so`

Comment: The uWSGI documentation on this point is horrendous to the point of idiotic. Why would you leave something critical like this out?